# Applying tabs with MixItUp plugin with one sorting/filter feature

Tags: jquery, html, css, sorting, filter

I have been trying to figure out on i can MixItUp plugin on Bootstrap tabs. My issue here on the first tab it works perfectly and functions correctly as seen here in the screenshot

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/SortFilter1_zps56e682d8.jpg

But when I check the second tab it has no content then the sorting/filter doesn’t work.

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/SortFilter2_zps33df07b7.jpg

I have been searching for answers on the docs to apply the plugin with tabs.

Here the code of my recent work.

```
<body>
<section class="container12">
<section class="column3 search_filter"> <!--START COL3-->
        <div class="refine_search">
            <h2>Refine Search</h2>

            <form class="controls" id="Filters">

            <!--RATING FILTER -->
            <fieldset>
                <h4>Rating</h4>

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input class="filter-one filter-two" type="checkbox" value=".fivestars"/>
                    <label>5 Stars</label>
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value=".fourstars"/>
                    <label>4 Stars</label>
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value=".threestars"/>
                    <label>3 Stars</label>
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value=".twostars"/>
                    <label>2 Stars</label>
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value=".onestar"/>
                    <label>1 Star</label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            </form>

        </div>
</section> <!--END COL3 -->

<div class="column9 search-filter">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="active"><a href="#philippines">Philippines</a></li>
            <li><a href="#malaysia">Malaysia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#singapore">Singapore</a></li>
            <li><a href="#hongkong">Hong Kong</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">

            <div class="tab-pane active" id="philippines">

                <div id="Container" class="column9 alpha search_results container "> 


                <div class="hotels mix fivestars">

                    <div class="hotel_thumbnail_container">

                        <div class="hotel_thumbnail">
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="hotel_details ">
                        <h3><a class="post_title" href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Hotel Post">Hotels</a></h3>
                        <span class="hotel_location">Philippines</span>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget condimentum diam, quis condimentum odio. Integer facilisis luctus dui eu adipiscing. </p>    

                    </div>

                     <div class="book_now">
                         <span class="hotel_rating fivestars ">Hotel Rating</span>
                         <h4 class="hotel_price">PHP<span>6000</span></h4>
                         <span class="book_link"><a href="">Book Now</a></span>
                     </div>


                </div>

                <div class="hotels mix fourstars">

                    <div class="hotel_thumbnail_container">

                        <div class="hotel_thumbnail">
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="hotel_details ">
                        <h3><a class="post_title" href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Hotel Post">Hotels</a></h3>
                        <span class="hotel_location">Philippines</span>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget condimentum diam, quis condimentum odio. Integer facilisis luctus dui eu adipiscing. </p>    

                    </div>

                     <div class="book_now">
                         <span class="hotel_rating fivestars ">Hotel Rating</span>
                         <h4 class="hotel_price">PHP<span>6000</span></h4>
                         <span class="book_link"><a href="">Book Now</a></span>
                     </div>


                </div>



                <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane" id="malaysia">
                <div id="Container" class="column9 alpha search_results container "> 


                <div class="hotels mix fivestars">

                    <div class="hotel_thumbnail_container">

                        <div class="hotel_thumbnail">
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="hotel_details ">
                        <h3><a class="post_title" href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Hotel Post">Hotels</a></h3>
                        <span class="hotel_location">Philippines</span>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget condimentum diam, quis condimentum odio. Integer facilisis luctus dui eu adipiscing. </p>    

                    </div>

                     <div class="book_now">
                         <span class="hotel_rating fivestars ">Hotel Rating</span>
                         <h4 class="hotel_price">PHP<span>6000</span></h4>
                         <span class="book_link"><a href="">Book Now</a></span>
                     </div>


                </div>

                <div class="hotels mix fourstars">

                    <div class="hotel_thumbnail_container">

                        <div class="hotel_thumbnail">
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="hotel_details ">
                        <h3><a class="post_title" href="#" rel="bookmark" title="Hotel Post">Hotels</a></h3>
                        <span class="hotel_location">Philippines</span>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris eget condimentum diam, quis condimentum odio. Integer facilisis luctus dui eu adipiscing. </p>    

                    </div>

                     <div class="book_now">
                         <span class="hotel_rating fivestars ">Hotel Rating</span>
                         <h4 class="hotel_price">PHP<span>6000</span></h4>
                         <span class="book_link"><a href="">Book Now</a></span>
                     </div>


                </div>



                <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="singapore">
            hotels
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="hongkong">
            cruises
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
</section>

<script>
var checkboxFilter = {

  $filters: null,
  $reset: null,
  groups: [],
  outputArray: [],
  outputString: '',


  init: function(){
    var self = this;

    self.$filters = $('#Filters');
    self.$reset = $('#Reset');
    self.$container = $('#Container');

    self.$filters.find('fieldset').each(function(){
      self.groups.push({
        $inputs: $(this).find('input'),
        active: [],
        tracker: false
      });
    });

    self.bindHandlers();
  },

  bindHandlers: function(){
    var self = this;

    self.$filters.on('change', function(){
      self.parseFilters();
    });

    self.$reset.on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      self.$filters[0].reset();
      self.parseFilters();
    });
  },


  parseFilters: function(){
    var self = this;

    for(var i = 0, group; group = self.groups[i]; i++){
      group.active = []; // reset arrays
      group.$inputs.each(function(){ 
        $(this).is(':checked') && group.active.push(this.value);
      });
        group.active.length && (group.tracker = 0);
    }

    self.concatenate();
  },

  concatenate: function(){
    var self = this,
          cache = '',
          crawled = false,
          checkTrackers = function(){
        var done = 0;

        for(var i = 0, group; group = self.groups[i]; i++){
          (group.tracker === false) && done++;
        }

        return (done < self.groups.length);
      },
      crawl = function(){
        for(var i = 0, group; group = self.groups[i]; i++){
          group.active[group.tracker] && (cache += group.active[group.tracker]);

          if(i === self.groups.length - 1){
            self.outputArray.push(cache);
            cache = '';
            updateTrackers();
          }
        }
      },
      updateTrackers = function(){
        for(var i = self.groups.length - 1; i > -1; i--){
          var group = self.groups[i];

          if(group.active[group.tracker + 1]){
            group.tracker++; 
            break;
          } else if(i > 0){
            group.tracker && (group.tracker = 0);
          } else {
            crawled = true;
          }
        }
      };

    self.outputArray = []; 

      do{
              crawl();
      }
      while(!crawled && checkTrackers());

    self.outputString = self.outputArray.join();

    !self.outputString.length && (self.outputString = 'all'); 

      if(self.$container.mixItUp('isLoaded')){
        self.$container.mixItUp('filter', self.outputString);
      }
  }
};


$(function(){

  checkboxFilter.init();

  $('#Container').mixItUp({
    animation: {
      easing: 'linear',
      duration: 400,
    }
  });    
});
</script>

<script>
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
})
</script>

</body>`
```

Comment: Same problem here, have you found a solution ?